# Thread safe while unzipping and deleting after reading unzipped file

Tags: java

I am writing a java code for reading a zip file which will unzip ,zipped file in current folder if it is not already unzipped by some other thread and then read that unzipped file. after reading unzipped file will be deleted.

For example : if I have a zip file test.zip at location /user/home then it will be unzipped at /user/home. after reading unzipped file file is deleted.

for single user it is working fine, but my concern is when multiple user try to access the same zip file (i.e. test.zip) and try to unzip it at same time. I am not able to handle this condition without impacting performance. I know I can use synchronization for unzip and delete method, but that will impact performance of my application, because second user have to wait till first request has been finished even if it is trying to unzip some other file.

Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks.

The JDK I'm using that contains javac is jdk1.6.0_35

Comment: Two different users will use two different processes, right?

Comment: I don't know if I got it right, but if you're working on the same file you can just synchronize the delete method. Two or more unzips can work together, but you've got to wait for each process to end before deleting the file. So, to summarize, try synchronizing just the file deletion and see if you get acceptable performances.

Comment: Create a different temporary directory every time you want to unzip, and unzip in that temporary directory. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29

Comment: use temp folder is a very good idea, but I can not use jdk7. Is there any method in java6 which provide temp folder creation, with proper error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is slightly more complex than what it looks like you were asking.

Correct me if I'm wrong but what you *really* seem to be asking is how to continue unzipping other files if an unzip on a given file is already in progress.

Sorry I want to answer this but don't have time to fully explain so hopefully this is clear.

If you don't mind unzipping the same file multiple times for multiple users at once then just unzip to a temporary location and be done with it.

If you don't mind taking up lots of storage then just unzip all the files ahead of time and leave them unzipped. You could even limit storage by deleting previously unzipped data that's gone unused for a certain amount of time, or deleting old data after a cache size threshold is hit.

But if you don't want to leave files unzipped and you don't want to unzip the same file multiple times at once: First start with the basics, e.g.:

```
class ZippedFile {
   public void beginAccess ();
   public void finishAccess ();
}
```

Where each user calls `beginAccess` when they want to access a zip file, and `finishAccess` when they are done. Next, you have to improve that a little to allow for synchronization:

```
class ZippedFile {
   public static final int BEGIN_ERROR = 0;
   public static final int BEGIN_BUSY = 1;
   public static final int BEGIN_OK = 2;
   private int refcount = 0;
   public void wantAccess ();   // synchronized internally
   public int beginAccess ();   // synchronized internally
   public void finishAccess (); // synchronized internally
}
```

Now with this, beginAccess should unzip the file and return BEGIN_OK normally. However, if another call to beginAccess is currently unzipping the file for another user, it should return BEGIN_BUSY immediately.

The wantAccess function should increase the reference count and do nothing else.

The finishAccess should decrease the reference count and delete the unzipped contents if it hits zero. If finishAccess is deleting the file while another user calls beginAccess, that call to beginAccess should also return BEGIN_BUSY.

So now you have a system that lets you unzip a file but at the same time continue on to the next file if the current one is being unzipped. The usage of wantAccess will become clearer below. Note that every wantAccess must be matched with exactly one finishAccess.

Now you have to make each user process multiple files, skipping busy ones and returning to them later. You can do that like this:

```
// in User somewhere...
void processFiles (List<ZippedFile> files) {

    LinkedList<ZippedFile> remaining = new LinkedList<ZippedFile>(files);

    // increase reference counts ahead of time so we hold the files
    // during this entire operation even if other users finish with
    // them in the mean time.
    for (ZippedFile file:remaining)
        file.wantAccess();

    while (!remaining.isEmpty()) {
        ZippedFile file = remaining.removeFirst();
        int status = file.beginAccess();
        if (status == ZippedFile.BEGIN_ERROR)
           file.finishAccess(); // decrease ref count 
        else if (status == ZippedFile.BEGIN_BUSY)
           remaining.addLast(file); // move to end of queue 
        else if (status == ZippedFile.BEGIN_OK) {
           processFileData(file); // do the work
           file.finishAccess(); // done with file
        }
    }

}
```

Be sure that your implementations of wantAccess, beginAccess, and finishAccess are implemented with appropriate synchronization. You can store an internal flag indicating whether or not the file has been completely unzipped, or if unzipping is in progress, and use that to prevent multiple unzips/deletes from happening at the same time -- you don't need to synchronize the unzips/deletes themselves.

The are probably other and more elegant ways but hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: An optimization is to use proper synchronization events to wait for files to unzip if everything remaining in the user's queue was busy; this will prevent you from sucking up CPU with a short loop waiting for the remaining files to finish.